# How to apply changes to HTML pages on Apache web server

Tags: apache

I am trying to update the website hosted on my Apache server (running on Fedora Server).

I tried doing both `system restart httpd` and `system reload httpd`, but when I open up a web browser and go to the site's IP address, the changes haven't applied. I viewed the source to confirm that the updated code wasn't there, and indeed the updated code was not there.

Comment: You may be seeing what is in your browser's cache.

Comment: That would make sense. I set `<Files ".ht*">` to `"Require all granted"`, and then made a .htaccess file at `/var/www/LecterandLecter/.htaccess` that contains the following: `<Files content.html>Header append Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate"</Files>` but that didn't change anything. I'm not sure if it's relevant, but that .htaccess file doesn't even appeal in a `ls` at `/var/www/LecterandLecter.`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the .htaccess was working, it just hadn't "kicked in" yet I guess. I set the `max-age` to 10 and the updates applied.